# How can I use the CakePHP APP class to load XML files from a URL?

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I am using the CakePHP XmlHelper to parse XML files like:

```
App::import('Xml');
$file = "my_xml_file.xml";
$parsed_xml =& new XML($file);
```

How can I use it to load XML files from URLs like http://www.site.com/file.xml

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple

```
App::import('Xml');
$url = "http://www.example.com/xml_file.xml";
$parsed_xml =& new XML($url);
```

Just using the URL instead of the file, Cake will internally choose the way to open the file

Comment: In cakephp 2, syntax would look different, check

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://www.site.com/file.xml");
$file = fopen("temp.xml", "rb");
fwrite($file, $contents);
fclose($file);
unset($contents)

App::import('Xml');
$file = "temp.xml";
$parsed_xml =& new XML($file);
```

:)