# Read RSS XML in CakePHP

Tags: xml, cakephp, rss

How read two or more files (rss, atom, etc.) by new XML()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at stackoverflow thread - [CakePHP XML loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492556/cakephp-xml-loading)